# Flutter WebSocket Channel with Binance API: Data updates only received once and then stops

Tags: flutter, dart, websocket, binance, candlestick-chart

Hello fellow developers,

I'm facing an issue with my Flutter code that involves retrieving real-time data from the Binance WebSocket API using the WebSocketChannel package. Initially, everything works fine as I'm able to fetch 40 data points from the API. However, after that, the stream seems to stop, and I'm no longer receiving any updates from the Binance API.

To provide some context, here's a snippet of my code:

```
final channel = WebSocketChannel.connect(
    // Uri.parse('wss://stream.binance.com:9443/ws/btcusdt@kline_1m'),
    // Uri.parse('wss://testnet.binance.vision/ws-api/v3'),
    Uri.parse('wss://ws-api.binance.com:9443/ws-api/v3'),
  );

  List<Candle> data = [];

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    fetchListenToStream();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    channel.sink.close();
    super.dispose();
  }
```

My function to fetch and stream the binance websocket api:

```
fetchListenToStream() async {
    channel.sink.add(
        '{"method":"klines","params":{"symbol": "BTCUSDT","interval": "12h","startTime": 1655969280000, "limit": ${data.length > 1 ? 1 : 40}},"id":"1dbbeb56-8eea-466a-8f6e-86bdcfa2fc0b"}');
    channel.stream.listen((event) async {
      // print(event);
      final newData = jsonDecode(event);

      if (newData['result'].length > 1) {
        List<Candle> streamData = (newData['result'] as List).map((klineData) {
          int timestamp = klineData[0];
          double open = double.parse(klineData[1]);
          double high = double.parse(klineData[2]);
          double low = double.parse(klineData[3]);
          double close = double.parse(klineData[4]);
          double volume = double.parse(klineData[5]);

          return Candle(
            open: open,
            high: high,
            low: low,
            close: close,
            volume: volume,
            date: DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch(timestamp),
          );
        }).toList();

        // print(streamData.length);

        setState(() {
          data.addAll(streamData);
        });
      } else {
        Candle incomingData = parseCandlestickData(event);
        setState(() {
          data.add(incomingData);
        });
      }
    });
  }




Candle parseCandlestickData(String data) {
    Map<String, dynamic> json = jsonDecode(data);
    List<dynamic> result = json['result'];

    if (result.isNotEmpty) {
      List<dynamic> klineData = result[0];

      if (klineData.length >= 11) {
        int timestamp = klineData[0];
        double open = double.parse(klineData[1]);
        double high = double.parse(klineData[2]);
        double low = double.parse(klineData[3]);
        double close = double.parse(klineData[4]);
        double volume = double.parse(klineData[5]);

        Candle candle = Candle(
          open: open,
          high: high,
          low: low,
          close: close,
          volume: volume,
          date: DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch(timestamp),
        );

        return candle;
      } else {
        throw const FormatException('Invalid kline data');
      }
    } else {
      throw const FormatException('Empty result array');
    }
  }
```

Displaying the data:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      color: cardColor,
      child: Column(children: [
        // Time change
        SizedBox(
          height: 500,
          child: Candlesticks(
            candles: data,
          ),
        )
      ]),
    );
  }
```

In the fetchListenToStream() method, I'm establishing a connection to the Binance WebSocket API and sending a request to retrieve candlestick data. The received data is then processed and added to the data list, which is used to display the candlestick chart using the Candlesticks widget from the `candlesticks` package.

The issue arises when after fetching the first 40 data from the api, it doesn't stream again and get's them one by one after that. The candlesticks package requires at least 13 data points in the list to function properly without throwing errors. However, if I try to fetch only one data point initially, the chart doesn't display properly and throws index range error.

I suspect that the problem lies in how I'm handling the WebSocket connection and listening to the stream. It seems that after the initial data retrieval, the stream stops, and I'm unable to fetch any further updates.

I would greatly appreciate any assistance or guidance in resolving this issue. How can I ensure that the WebSocket connection remains active and continues to fetch data from the Binance API? Is there a better approach or strategy to handle the continuous streaming of data from the WebSocket?

Thank you in advance for your valuable input and expertise.